# Median length of interval between pairs of successive timestamps

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, window-functions, postgresql-9.5

I have a table with `timestamp` column (`timestamp with time zone`). I want to know the median length of the interval between each pair of successive timestamps.

For example, with timestamps (on the same day) of `08:00`, `08:10`, `08:30`, `09:00`, I want `20 minutes` because the median interval between successive timestamps is 20 minutes.

I've been trying stuff with window functions and lead/lag, but without success.

This code may be helpful in setting up the situation.

```
CREATE TABLE timestamps (
    "timestamp" timestamp with time zone
);
COPY timestamps ("timestamp") FROM stdin;
2017-08-02 08:00:53.550685-00
2017-08-02 08:10:53.550685-00
2017-08-02 08:30:53.550685-00
2017-08-02 09:00:53.550685-00
\.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) WITHIN GROUP(ORDER by X) FROM 
(
SELECT *,
       timestamps - lag(timestamps) over (order by timestamps) As x
FROM Table1
) x
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9bfe9/5